# How to add additional traces in plotly express scatter plot with correct z-order?

Tags: plotly

I want to plot some context to an animated graph. I figured out how to add an extra trace to the figure by calling `fig.add_trace`:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(new_data, 
                 x="X-coord", 
                 y="Y-coord", 
                 animation_frame="Timepoint",
                 color="Fraction", 
                 hover_name="Compound",
                 size_max=10,
                 size='Fraction')

fig.add_traces(g.edge_trace)
```

fig

[image]

But the trace is drawn above the points. I want the lines behind the markers. I tried to switch the order of `fig.data`, but that does not work correctly in an animated plot. And also the legend is interfering with the colorbar.

Comment: I data sample or description of your data source would be helpful